# How to find in page in google chrome mobile?

Tags: chrome-for-android

How to find in page in google chrome mobile? You used to be able to type in the omnibox and an magnifying glass icon would appear on one line.  Clicking on that would enable one to find in page.  In the new version it has disappeared so how does it work now?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you click the three dots menu you should see a 'Find in page' option which allows you to enter the text to look for.

[image: Menu]

Comment: Duh! Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @DarrynBrisdaz easily done! It's interesting, I haven't been a fan of Google's move away from icons towards the wording, it looks a little too much on a small screen at times.